# Why when I use a string "&&", it only shows "&" on the form label?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
str = "&&";            
label1.Text = str;
```

but it only shows "&".

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try putting a @ sign in front of the label: `label1.Text = str;` where `str = @"&&";`. What are the <i></i> about?

Comment: Did you notice the underline when you use a single &?

Comment: @Killercam: That won't work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because the & (ampersand) is known as a mnemonic and it is being interpreted as such. Double-ampersand (&&) comes out as "Text & Text" when you do "Text && Text".

You can set the Label.UseMnemonic property to false. The default is true.

Answer (score 1):

The & means that the character after the & becomes the shortcut key. When that form has the focus pressing Alt+*Shortcut Key* will shift the focus to that control.

For a label, it shifts the focus to the control that is in the tab order following the label.

This means you can't just use the & character in the label as it has that special meaning. So to allow you to use the & in the label Windows lets you use &&. So setting the label text to be `&&` will set the label of the text to be `&`.